# Pentaho Kafka producer example

Tags: pentaho, apache-kafka

I am trying to create a transformation using Kafka producer and consumer in Pentaho Data Integration. Is there any example available in Pentaho for Apache Kafka Producer and Consumer? or can you please let me know how to create the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download a plugin to enable your apache kafka. This [DOC](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Apache+Kafka+Producer)
shows you how to use Apache Kafka in PDI. Hope it helps :)

Comment: The Kafka plugin is available directly via the PDI Marketplace (versus the download page from the above link), to get to the Marketplace in Spoon, go to the Help drop-down menu and select Marketplace